# Maven Installation under Windows: "JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory"

Tags: java, maven

I'm new to Maven and I have downloaded the 3.0.5 version. I'm getting the following error:

```
JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory. please set the java_home variable in your environment variable to match the location of your java installation
```

Although, I see no error when I type `javac` or echo `%M2_HOME%` in the command prompt.

I have the following path variables set  -

```
CLASSPATH - ;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\lib;
JAVA_HOME - C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\bin
M2 - %M2_HOME%\bin
M2_HOME - C:\Users\cbil\Documents\Maven\apache-maven-3.0.5-bin\apache-maven-3.0.5
MAVEN_OPTS - -Xms256m -Xmx512m
PATH - C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin;C:\Users\cbil\Documents\Maven\apache-maven-3.0.5-bin\apache-maven-3.0.5\bin;
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: This is likely an issue with the space in "Program Files".  Also, add the trailing \ at the end of the path:

Answer (score 17):

- `M2_HOME` points to the directory where maven is installed.
- `M2` points to the *bin* directory under maven
- `JAVA_HOME` points to the JDK directory installed on your system.

validate it again from below settings:

```
JAVA_HOME   - C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_23
M2_HOME     - D:\Software\apache-maven-3.0.5
M2          - %M2_HOME%\bin
PATH        - %M2%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin
```

Answer (score 4):

JAVA_HOME should be set to jdk installation directory and not to the bin folder.

It should work, once the path is set properly.

Answer (score 4):

Read the official documentation. The [**Maven Installation Instructions**](http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi#Installation) for Windows are pretty simple to follow.

> **Windows**
>
> - Unzip the distribution archive, i.e. apache-maven-3.2.1-bin.zip to the
>     directory you wish to install Maven 3.2.1. These instructions assume
>     you chose C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation. The
>     subdirectory apache-maven-3.2.1 will be created from the archive.
> - Add the M2_HOME environment variable by opening up the system properties
>     (WinKey + Pause), selecting the "Advanced" tab, and the "Environment
>     Variables" button, then adding the M2_HOME variable in the user
>     variables with the value C:\Program Files\Apache Software
>     Foundation\apache-maven-3.2.1. Be sure to omit any quotation marks
>     around the path even if it contains spaces. Note: For Maven 2.0.9,
>     also be sure that the M2_HOME doesn't have a '\' as last character.
> - In the same dialog, add the M2 environment variable in the user variables
>     with the value %M2_HOME%\bin.
> - Optional: In the same dialog, add the
>     MAVEN_OPTS environment variable in the user variables to specify JVM
>     properties, e.g. the value -Xms256m -Xmx512m. This environment
>     variable can be used to supply extra options to Maven.
> - In the same dialog, update/create the Path environment variable in the user
>     variables and prepend the value %M2% to add Maven available in the
>     command line.
> - In the same dialog, make sure that JAVA_HOME exists in
>     your user variables or in the system variables and it is set to the
>     location of your JDK, e.g. C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51 and that
>     %JAVA_HOME%\bin is in your Path environment variable.
> - Open a new command prompt (Winkey + R then type cmd) and run mvn --version to
>     verify that it is correctly installed.

Comment: This is what I needed to see- thanks. Works for me.

Answer (score 3):

To set JAVA_HOME

`set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_40`

To add `mvn` to path

`set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Users\cbil\Documents\Maven\apache-maven-3.0.5-bin\apache-maven-3.0.5\bin;`

Answer (score 3):

Inside your system variables, set JAVA_HOME

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45
```

and inside path, add these:

```
 C:\maven\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;
```

The error is caused due to non readability of the java path .